# How to logout ClaimsIdentity User when using OpenIDConnect

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect, identityserver3

I have ASP.NET Core application that is using OpenIDConnect authentication. In `OnTokenValidated` event i check if `Authenticated` user exists in the my application's database, and if not then i am throwing `UnauthorizedAccessException`

Note that in `OnTokenValidated` event i am creating new identity if user exists in the application's DB, else i leave authenticated user as it is.

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly ILogger<Startup> _logger;
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    private IHostingEnvironment _environment { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        _environment = env;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
         .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
         {
             options.LoginPath = "/Home";
             options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/Forbidden";
             options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder()
             {
                 Name = "myCookie",
                 HttpOnly = true,
             };
             options.SlidingExpiration = true;
         })
         .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
         {
             //options.ForwardChallenge                
             options.Authority = configuration["IdentityOptions:Authority"];
             options.ClientId = configuration["IdentityOptions:ClientID"];
             options.ResponseType = "id_token";
             options.CallbackPath = "/Home";
             options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; //tells cookies scheme to persist user's identity in cookie.
             options.SignOutScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;//tells cookies scheme to remove persisted cookie
             options.Scope.Add(OpenIdConnectScope.Email);
             
             options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
             {
                 OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                 {
                     var emailClaim = context.Principal.Claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Email);
                     
                    // check if user exists in client applications db
                     CompanyUser cu = null;
                     using (var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
                     {
                         using (var serviceScope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
                         {
                             using (var accountService = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IAccountService>())
                             {
                                 cu = await accountService.Authorize(emailClaim.Value);
                             }
                         }
                     }

                     if (cu == null)
                     {
                         // context.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated is true here
                         
                         throw new UnauthorizedAccessException(string.Format("Could not find user for login '{0}' ", emailClaim.Value));
                     }

                     //We will create new identity to store only required claims.
                     var newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Principal.Identity.AuthenticationType);

                     // keep the id_token for logout 
                     newIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(IdentityClaimTypes.IdToken, context.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

                     // add email claim
                     newIdentity.AddClaim(emailClaim);                         
                     
                     context.Properties.IsPersistent = true;
                     context.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(3);

                     // overwrite existing authentication ticket
                     context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(newIdentity);
                 },                     
                 OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = async context =>
                 {
                     var idTokenHint = context.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirst("id_token");
                     if (idTokenHint != null)
                         context.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                     await Task.FromResult(0);
                 },
                 OnRemoteFailure = async context =>
                 {  
                     //WHY context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false here??
                     if (context.Failure is UnauthorizedAccessException)
                     {
                         context.Response.Redirect("/Account/AccessDenied");
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         context.Response.Redirect("/Account/Error");
                     }
                     context.HandleResponse();
                     await Task.FromResult(0);
                 }
             };
         });
    }
```

}

**Questions**

1> In `OnRemoteFailure` How do i auto logout/clear `unauthorized` user BEFORE redirecting to AccessDenied view? `AccessDenied` view is accessible to anonymous user.
I have tried

```
OnRemoteFailure = async context =>
                     {
                         if (context.Failure is UnauthorizedAccessException)
                         {
                             await Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignOutAsync(context.HttpContext, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                             await Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignOutAsync(context.HttpContext, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

                             context.Response.Redirect("/Account/AccessDenied");
                         }
                         else 
                         {
                             context.Response.Redirect("/Account/Error");
                         }
                         context.HandleResponse();
                         await Task.FromResult(0);
                     }
```

However in `OnTokenValidated` event `context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is false so it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

A common mistake is to do a Reponse.Redirect after the Signout method calls, that sounds obvious. But that does unfortunately not work. The Signout methods creates their own redirect responses and when you do your redirect you "override" these redirects

The proper way to do implement this is to not return anything and let the Signout methods handle the redirect:

```
    public async Task DoLogout()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
```

To redirect to an alternative Url, you can try:

```
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new AuthenticationProperties( )
        {
            RedirectUri = "alternativeUrl"
        });
```

Comment: I tried this, but this will redirect user to identity server's logged out page. I want user to goto AccessDenied page.  I tried `public async Task<IActionresult> AccessDenied()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
  return View("AccessDenied");
    }`  Did not work

Comment: it does get redirected. May be i have asked wrong question here. I have started a new thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63042878/how-to-overwrite-post-logout-redirect-url

Comment: Its always good to clarify your question. However, why not set AuthenticationProperties { redirectUri} on both Signout methods? or try to change the order of them?

Comment: If you don't get it to work you can always as a hack  just clear the local session cookie to signout the user locally.

Comment: Are you happy with my answer or are there something missing? If not, please mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: Not doing the redirect back to the home is what finally worked for me.