# How to overwrite post logout redirect url

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, identityserver3

I am using IdentityServer3 and i have ASP.NET Core as Client application.

Here is my LoggOff action method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task LogOff()
    {
        await Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignOutAsync(HttpContext, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        await Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignOutAsync(HttpContext, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
```

When user logs out i see the following redirects in fiddler

```
   GET /identity/connect/endsession?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44352%2Fsignout-callback-oidc&state=XXXXXX&x-client-SKU=XXXXXX&x-client-ver=5.3.0.0 HTTP/1.1

   GET /identity/logout?id=XXXXXXXXXX 

   GET /identity/connect/endsessioncallback?sid=XXXXXXX
```

and eventually in browser url is set to `/identity/logout?id=XXXXXXXXXX`. These are identity server's URL not Client Application URL.

This is working as expected when logoff button invokes `LogOff` action method.

Now i have a requirement. When user goes to `AccessDenied` page i want to logoff user first,and then redirect to `AccessDenied` view. The `AccessDenied` page is in ClientAppliction. So i have another action method that invokes SingnOut and set `RedirectUri`

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task AccessDenied()
    {
        await Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignOutAsync(HttpContext, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        await Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignOutAsync(HttpContext,
            OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties()
            {
                RedirectUri = "Account/AccessDenied"
            });
    }
```

This is not working. User still goes to `identity/logout` instead of `AccessDenied`. Looks like it is not setting post logout redirect uri.

Comment: Did you figure out a way to fix this? I am experiencing a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Its not a typo that you forgot to prefix the url with / ?

like

```
RedirectUri = "/Account/AccessDenied"
```

instead of

```
RedirectUri = "Account/AccessDenied"
```

Comment: That would result in a HTTP 404 error if that was the case